# Nativescript: How to use navigation in modals

Tags: ios, navigation, modal-dialog, frame, nativescript

I am creating a settings modal in my app, and I would like to be able to "navigate" to categories of settings within the modal.

There are examples of this in apps, like Flipboard for example. If you open the settings, a modal opens, and you can tap a category. It navigates you to a new page (still within the modal), and you get a back button that will bring you back to the modal page. When you close the modal, your navigation stack is still valid, they seem to be two separate stacks. You can even navigate deeper, like open settings > Edit Profile > Change Email. You then can go back twice to get back to the main modal and close it by tapping done. Possible in {N}?

[image: flipboard settings]

Comment: What do you mean by nativescript. I know we can achieve this by `UINavigationViewController`. We will use push and pop functions to do this. Initial Modal is the rootViewController for this.

Comment: Nativescript is a framework where you build native mobile apps with javascript. https://www.nativescript.org/