# In NativeScript, how do I change page/view in a modal page?

Tags: modal-dialog, nativescript

I would like to create a multiple step modal dialog - like a wizard. A series of screens that follow on from one another.

I'm using the code from NativeScript's site to display a modal (https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#modal-pages)

```
var modalPageModule = "./modal-views-demo/login-page";
var context = "some custom context";
var fullscreen = true;
mainPage.showModal(modalPageModule, context, function closeCallback(username, password) {
    // Log the user in...
}, fullscreen);
```

The code works, but I'm unsure how to change the `modalPageModule` once the modal is displayed.

**Possible duplicate**

[Nativescript: How to use navigation in modals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771855/nativescript-how-to-use-navigation-in-modals)
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3753